# Is there a way to have named indexes on array_map output?

Tags: php, indexing, array-map

I have the code below:

```
array_map(
    function (ReflectionParameter $parameter){

        $paramName = $parameter->getName();

        return $this->params[$paramName];
    ,
    $this->getParametersNeededByTheConstructor()
);
```

It outputs something like:

> 1. [0] => 'ParamValue'
> 2. [2] => 'ParamValue'
> 3. [3] => 'ParamValue'
> 4. [4] => 'ParamValue'
> 5. [5] => 'ParamValue'

Is there a way to set the array indexes in the code above? For example:

> 1. [paramName0] => 'ParamValue'
> 2. [paramName2] => 'ParamValue'
> 3. [paramName3] => 'ParamValue'
> 4. [paramName4] => 'ParamValue'
> 5. [paramName5] => 'ParamValue'

Comment: As you are passing only one array to `array_map()`, the keys will be preserved. So in this case the easiest solution would be to have `$this->getParametersNeededByTheConstructor()` return an array with the keys you need.

Comment: Ow! That's new for me! Thank you! But, i want the indexes getting the reflection parameter name, not the index name of the old array passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this with `array_map`, but you can just use a simple `foreach` loop.

```
$params = [];
foreach ($this->getParametersNeededByTheConstructor() as $parameter) {
    $paramName = $parameter->getName();
    $params[$paramName] = $this->params[$paramName];
}
```

If your IDE doesn't automatically detect the type of the loop variable, you can wrap the body in an anonymous function

```
$params = [];
foreach ($this->getParametersNeededByTheConstructor() as $parameter) {
    (function(ReflectionParameter $parameter) {
        $paramName = $parameter->getName();
        $params[$paramName] = $this->params[$paramName];
    })($parameter);
}
```

Comment: I want to use array_map because it lets me specify the type of the current parameter i'm working with. That helps my IDE providing code snippets, something that i'm not seeing how to make works with a foreach loop.

Comment: See my updated answer for one solution. Although in theory it would be possible for your IDE to to get the type of the value you're looping over if the return type of `getParametersNeededByTheConstructor` was declared.

Comment: Thaaank you! How i did not even think about it?

Answer (score 1):

To get from your current array to the expected you can use array combine and a foreach loop.
The loop creates the new array with the key values and array combine uses the keys as keys in the new array and the values of original array as values.

```
$arr = array( 0=> 'ParamValue',
2 => 'ParamValue',
3 => 'ParamValue',
4 => 'ParamValue',
5 => 'ParamValue');

$keys =array();

Foreach($arr as $key =>$val){
    $keys[] = $val . $key;
}

$result = array_combine($keys, $arr);

Var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/vTWjs

Comment: I want to use array_map because it lets me specify the type of the current parameter i'm working with. That helps my IDE providing code snippets, something that i'm not seeing how to make works with a foreach loop.

Comment: @e200 an IDE's intellisense is not a very good reason to prefer bad code over good code.

Comment: Yep, but it also help who will read the code to understand it.